# How to put a <img> inside a <p> without transpassing border height?

Tags: html, css, image, icons

I'm new in `Html/CSS` and now I'm trying to make a website (using only html and css) for a friend. In the footer I want to put a `img` like in this `photo`: [How I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alsHL.png)

But, All I could do, until now, was that:

[What I could do until now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22olu.png)

I could put the text and make the border the way I wanted, I could put a kind of blue color when the mouse hover and to be clickable in all the border space. **But, I'm not beeing able to put this icon image righ inside. Can you help me?**

Thanks a lot!

```css
    #footer {
     height: 500px;
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 0;
     background: #b6b6b6;
     display: table;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
    }

    #atua {
     width: 30%;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: initial;
    }

    .job {
     border: 2px solid #ffffff;
     width: 75%;
     height: 35px;
     margin: 0;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     padding-top: 8px;
     padding-left: 50px;
    }

    div #atua a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #ffffff;
    }

    div .job:hover {
     background-color: #14aca9;
```

```html
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="atua">
        <h3>&Aacute;rea de Atua&ccedil;&atilde;o</h3>
        <a href="#"><p class="job">Trabalhista</p></a>
        <a href="#"><p class="job">Empresarial</p></a>
        <a href="#"><p class="job">Previdenci&aacute;rio</p></a>
        <a href="#"><p class="job">C&iacute;vil</p></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please provide your code here

Comment: Hello there, I edited the post to provide the code =) Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an HTML/CSS version of what you want.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51885970e4b0d20f07f4329d/t/519d043ae4b0f5d1146aa6ca/1369244735750/HD+TEXTURE+1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 3px;}
a span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-image: url('http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/tropical-blue/square-xxl.png');
  background-size: 39px 39px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a:hover span {
  background-color: #14aca9;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Trabalhista</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

What I'm trying to do is to put a image just in the left, like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/alsHL.png

=/

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you want. I thought you were looking for the black background image extends beyond the white border. I updated my answer.

Comment: smdsgn, your code works the way I wanted =D Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome @ThassioPaganucciXavier.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your code but if you want a simple answer this might help.

```
<footer style="height:100px;text-align:center;">
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="click.jpg" height="100"/><a>
</footer>
```